# How to choose best Bi Pi and R (Base,Power,Reminder) using python

Tags: python, algorithm, math

How can we find out nearest best exponent for a large digit in **python** suppose I have a number like "**X**". I want to write this number in the form of an exponent like as follows:

```
X=B1^P1 + B2^P2 + B3^P3 + .... + Bn^Pn + R
```

Example: let's say X=99, then I can write

```
X=99= 9^2 + 4 ^ 2 + 2
```

Or

```
X=99= 9^2 + 18
```

Or maybe there will be N solutions, same thing I am doing in python for a large number here is [the link](https://repl.it/IHMY/9)

Here 
B1, B2, B3,...... Bn means Base

P1, P2, P3,...... Pn means Power

R means Reminder

**In short**

Suppose I have a number like **2598**.

I want to write this number like as follows (using python)

```
2599=7^4+14^2+1
```

Comment: What is the "best" set of *Bi* and *Pi*?

Comment: I have added description now for base power and reminder

Comment: I get what they mean, but you have the word "best" in your title. How do you choose what's a good solution? `R = X` is trivial, but why would it be invalid?

Comment: @Blender bi and pi can be any thing that is what I want to find out.

Comment: So set B1 = B2 = ... = 0 and P1 = P2 = ... = 0 and R = X. Are you trying to find every single solution? Some of them? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: okay please check this https://repl.it/IHMY/16

Comment: In above example I am just taking square roots of the number and my number is too large so I am taking nearest square root using newtons square root theorem and I am finding exponent with reminder

Comment: Why does that solution not work?

Comment: This is one solutions but my client is saying power may be any number not only square that's why I am asking thanks

Comment: You can see first time base is too much and power is only 2.... so my client need different solution

Comment: @Blender And now if your doubt is clear than please change question status unclear thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean, these functions will get you what you want but only for the largest squares.

```
import math

def f(n):
    """ Returns closest square. """
    return math.floor(math.sqrt(n)) ** 2

def getlargestsquares(n):
    """ Returns a list of the largest squares that add up to n. """
    squares = []
    while n > 0:
        square = f(n)
        squares.append(square)
        n -= square
    return squares
```

Comment: I don't want square I want answer like
x^y + z ^ w +...... + A ^ B + Reminder